How can I mod my S24 ultra to run linux nethunter?- installed via termux?
S24 ultra link to Macbook pro  for O.S.  Can i install nethunter on it via usb c from macbook pro2018 without registering ?
Macbook pro 2018,sequoia o.s.15.1
Usb c link
S24 ULTRA 1Tb ro memory 16Gbram
CPu MT6762
Ive got phone mechanic on my macbook.
Its not linking properly.
Not recognised by disk utility. How do i make it discoverable?
Ill learn to use the shell terminal if anyone would give instruçtions!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
